VMware Workstation 17 Pro wont's show guest applications on host
I freshly installed VMware Workstation 17.5 Pro on Windows 10 and created a new VM with Windows 10. After entering Unity mode the applications running on the guest are not added to the host's taks list or are accessable in any other way from the host. VMware tools are installed in the guest OS.
Any ideas what could be the issue there?

dnot use 17.5.2 version, rollback 17.5.1 with full reinstall.
https://www.reddit.com/r/vmware/comments/1ct72nn/1752_build23775571_wm_tools_issue/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
